# Conditional probability given two events

Tags: probability

Is the following probability correct given that $W$ and $H$ depend on $G$?

$$P(G\mid w,h) = \frac{P(w\mid G)\cdot P(h\mid G)\cdot P(G)}{\left(P(w\mid G) P(G)+P(w\mid \overline{G}) P(\overline{G})\right) \cdot \left(P(h\mid G) P(G)+P(h\mid \overline{G}) P(\overline{G})\right)} $$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site. Please make the question self-contained without relying on external links. If they go stale, any answers to your question would lose their value.

Comment: ty very much for the tutorial and the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More information on the dependancies of W and H is needed.

Generally:

$$\mathsf P(G\mid W,H) ~=~ \dfrac{\mathsf P(W, H\mid G)~\mathsf P(G)}{\mathsf P(W, H)}$$

Now, *if* events $W$ and $H$ depend on event $G$ *but* are **conditionally independent** given $G$, then the numerator you want occurs:

$$\mathsf P(G\mid W,H) ~=~ \dfrac{\color{navy}{\mathsf P(W\mid G)~\mathsf P(H\mid G)~\mathsf P(G)}}{\mathsf P(W\mid G)~\mathsf P(H\mid G)~\mathsf P(G)+\mathsf P(W\mid\overline G)~\mathsf P(H\mid\overline G)~\mathsf P(\overline G)}$$

On the other hand *if* events $W$ and $H$ depend on event $G$ *but* are **pairwise independent**, then the denominator you want occurs:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(G\mid W,H) ~=~& \dfrac{\mathsf P(W, H\mid G)~\mathsf P(G)}{\mathsf P(W)~\mathsf P(H)}
\\ = ~& \dfrac{\mathsf P(W, H\mid G)~\mathsf P(G)}{\color{navy}{\Big(\mathsf P(W\mid G)~\mathsf P(G)+\mathsf P(W\mid\overline G)~\mathsf P(\overline G)\Big)~\Big(\mathsf P(H\mid G)~\mathsf P(G)+\mathsf P(H\mid\overline G)~\mathsf P(\overline G)\Big)}}
\end{align}$$

To mix and match, both scenarios would need to be so.

Comment: great explanation ty, and yes my mistake was the denominator I computed W and H as pairwise independent instead of conditionally independent.